# How can I attach a light to a tiled wall without having a socket (also avoid drilling)

Tags: lighting, bathroom, tile, light-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

In the bathroom the sink has as usual above a mirror. The wall behind the mirror and the sink has tiles.
The light is only in the ceiling.
How could I add some light (source) above the mirror if there is no electric socket to put a bulb?
Is there some kind of lights that can be "glued" on tiles? Same as IKEA sells for e.g. soap or shampoo etc.
I would prefer to avoid some light stand that is in the bathroom. Is there any good solution?

Comment: low voltage led strip lighting sounds good. a lot of them come sticky backed...

Comment: @dandavis:hm I would like ideally to have a decent lightning intensity

Comment: that's no problem with decent LED strips; with 5m @~15v of strip there's no apparent surface spot in my bathroom under 220 lux (w/o dimming), though i've not measured behind the commode...

Comment: @dandavis: You are describing something like this? https://www.amazon.com/Brilliant-Evolution-BRRC135-Wireless-Control/dp/B01JTA4QXI/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1507283469&sr=8-6&keywords=LED+light+with+remote

Comment: more like 5m of 5050 LED warm white strip. Some cheap ones are ghastly, but i've found http://www.ebay.com/itm/252371081346 to be nice, which should be ~$5, or a kit with driver should be ~$10-$20. within a week of my first roll, I had 4 more on the way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution in this case may be to just get a light weight LED light that operates on batteries. Then stick it up on the wall using some of that double stick foam tape.

You may be able to find some LED light that can be hung from a hook. Then there are strong stick-on hooks that you can attach to the tile wall.

Comment: Plenty of tap lights come with adhesive on them. The real question is if above the mirror is within easy reach or if you'd need a remote.

Comment: How can I search for it? Is there an example I can use for reference?

Comment: Search at www.amazon.com with"led tap light". You will find a plethora of stick on low power LED lights that turn on and off by touch.

Comment: Something like this set of 6 LED puck lights with a remote control may be applicable: https://www.amazon.com/Brilliant-Evolution-BRRC135-Wireless-Control/dp/B01JTA4QXI/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1507283469&sr=8-6&keywords=LED+light+with+remote

Comment: @MichaelKaras: Do these have a decent luminosity/intensity?

Comment: @Jim - Only you can decide what is "decent intensity".

Comment: @MichaelKaras: Fair enough. I'll try them. To be honest I was trying to find a solution that also has a good/clear lighting but I don't know the proper terms to define what I mean (equivalent of white bulb > 70W I guess?)